# Run protoc command into docker container

Tags: docker, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-node

I'm trying to run `protoc` command into a docker container.

I've tried using the [gRPC image](https://hub.docker.com/r/grpc/node) but `protoc` command is not found:

> /bin/sh: 1: protoc: not found

So I assume I have to install manually using `RUN` instructions, but is there a better solution? An official precompiled image with `protoc` installed?

Also, I've tried to install via Dockerfile but I'm getting again `protoc: not found`.

This is my Dockerfile

```
#I'm not using "FROM grpc/node" because that image can't unzip
FROM node:12 

...

# Download proto zip
ENV PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.14.0-linux-x86_32.zip
RUN curl -OL https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.14.0/${PROTOC_ZIP}
RUN unzip -o ${PROTOC_ZIP} -d ./proto 
RUN chmod 755 -R ./proto/bin
ENV BASE=/usr/local
# Copy into path
RUN cp ./proto/bin/protoc ${BASE}/bin
RUN cp -R ./proto/include/* ${BASE}/include

RUN protoc -I=...
```

I've done `RUN echo $PATH` to ensure the folder is in path and is ok:

```sh
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Also `RUN ls -la /usr/local/bin` to check `protoc` file is into the folder and it shows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4849692 Jan  2 11:16 protoc
```

So the file is in /bin folder and the folder is in the path.

Have I missed something?

Also, is there a simple way to get the image with `protoc` installed? or the best option is generate my own image and pull from my repository?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Solved downloading `linux-x86_64` zip file instead of `x86_32`. I downloaded the lower architecture requirements thinking a `x86_64` machine can run a `x86_32` file but not in the other way. I don't know if I'm missing something about architecture requirements (It's probably) or is a bug.

Anyway in case it helps someone I found the solution and I've added an answer with the neccessary Dockerfile to run `protoc` and `protoc-gen-grpc-web`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved my own issue.

The problem was the arch version: I was using `linux-x86_32.zip` but works using `linux-x86_64.zip`

Even [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65539101/13464279) answer is incredible and so complete, it didn't solve my problem because using `apt-get` install version `3.0.0` and I wanted `3.14.0`.

So, the Dockerfile I have used to run `protoc` into a docker container is like this:

```
FROM node:12

... 

# Download proto zip
ENV PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.14.0-linux-x86_64.zip
RUN curl -OL https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.14.0/${PROTOC_ZIP}
RUN unzip -o ${PROTOC_ZIP} -d ./proto 
RUN chmod 755 -R ./proto/bin
ENV BASE=/usr
# Copy into path
RUN cp ./proto/bin/protoc ${BASE}/bin/
RUN cp -R ./proto/include/* ${BASE}/include/

# Download protoc-gen-grpc-web
ENV GRPC_WEB=protoc-gen-grpc-web-1.2.1-linux-x86_64
ENV GRPC_WEB_PATH=/usr/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-web
RUN curl -OL https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/releases/download/1.2.1/${GRPC_WEB}
# Copy into path
RUN mv ${GRPC_WEB} ${GRPC_WEB_PATH}
RUN chmod +x ${GRPC_WEB_PATH}

RUN protoc -I=...
```

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to get non-default tools like this is to install them through the underlying Linux distribution's package manager.

First, look at the [Docker Hub page for the `node` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node).  (For "library" images like `node`, construct the URL `https://hub.docker.com/_/node`.)  You'll notice there that there are several variations named "alpine", "buster", or "stretch"; plain `node:12` is the same as `node:12-stretch` and `node:12.20.0-stretch`.  The "alpine" images are based on Alpine Linux; the "buster" and "stretch" ones are different versions of Debian GNU/Linux.

For Debian-based packages, you can then look up the package on https://packages.debian.org/ (type `protoc` into the "Search the contents of packages" form at the bottom of the page).  That leads you to the [`protobuf-compiler` package](https://packages.debian.org/stable/devel/protobuf-compiler).  Knowing that contains the `protoc` binary, you can install it in your Dockerfile with:

```sh
FROM node:12 # Debian-based
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      protobuf-compiler
# The rest of your Dockerfile as above
COPY ...
RUN protoc ...
```

You generally must run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` in the same `RUN` command, lest a subsequent rebuild get an old version of the package cache from the Docker build cache.  I generally have only a single `apt-get install` command if I can manage it, with the packages list alphabetically one to a line for maintainability.

If the image is Alpine-based, you can do a similar search on https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents to find [`protoc`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/main/x86_64/protoc), and similarly install it:

```sh
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache protoc
# The rest of your Dockerfile as above
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, but `apt-get` install version 3.0.0, not 3.14.0. I will test if 3.0.0 works fine too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Because this is currently the highest ranked result on Google and the above instructions above won't work, if you want to use `docker/dind` for e.g. gitlab, this is the way how you can get the glibc-dependency working for `protoc` there:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# install gcompat, because protoc needs a real glibc or compatible layer
apk add gcompat

# install a recent protoc (use a version that fits your needs)
export PB_REL="https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases"
curl -LO $PB_REL/download/v3.20.0/protoc-3.20.0-linux-x86_64.zip
unzip protoc-3.20.0-linux-x86_64.zip -d $HOME/.local
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```